# UISegmentedControl Doesn't Deselect Old Segment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl in a UITableView Table row. The selection fires, and the new segment is highlighted. The problem is, the old segment remains selected.

If I close and reopen the popover that contains the table, the correct segment index is displayed.

I'm running XCode 6.1 and testing on iOS 7.1 simulator.

Assistance appreciated.

```
UITableViewCell *segmentCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:segmentCellIdentifier];
if (segmentCell == nil) {
segmentCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:segmentCellIdentifier];
    }
segmentCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
segmentCell.backgroundView = nil;
NSArray *segmentItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSLocalizedString(@"settingsBackgroundCork", @"Cork - Select cork background theme"), NSLocalizedString(@"settingsBackgroundDark", @"Dark - Select dark background theme"), NSLocalizedString(@"settingsBackgroundLight", @"Light - Select light background theme"), nil];
self.backgroundSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems: segmentItems];
[self.backgroundSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundControlChanged:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.backgroundSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 6, 300, 32);
NSInteger background = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kUserDefaultsBackgroundSelection];
self.backgroundSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = background;
self.backgroundSegmentedControl.momentary = NO;
[segmentCell.contentView addSubview:self.backgroundSegmentedControl];
cellToReturn = segmentCell;
```

[image]

Here is the method that gets called on segment selection:

```
- (void)backgroundControlChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)control
{
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setInteger:control.selectedSegmentIndex forKey:kUserDefaultsBackgroundSelection];
self.backgroundSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = control.selectedSegmentIndex;
[self.backgroundSegmentedControl setNeedsDisplay];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kPageBackgroundShouldChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Does your table view scroll, and if so, do you only see this effect after you've scrolled?

Comment: The tableview is scroll capable. That said this element is at the top, and visible without requiring any scrolling to be displayed. I'm not scrolling when I test this (i.e. row is not being redrawn).

Comment: The only way I could duplicate your problem was with scrolling. One problem you code has, is that you will be adding new segmented controllers on top of old ones when you reuse a cell. It would be better to create a subclassed cell, and add the segmented control in its init method. Or, you could check if a cell contains a segmented control before adding one in cellFroRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I'm having the same weird issue. The result is a little different if I put the segmented controls' creation in a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}) block, but it still doesn't behave correctly.. I resorted to making a similar control completely from scratch. This is indeed a strange issue.

Answer (score 0):

Strange bug - I never saw this before. Two suggestions:

- Try setting the `selectedSegmentIndex` again in the handler, and
- Try calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the control there as well.

`momentary` is `NO` by default, so you should not need to set it.

Also, in the `selectedSegmentIndex` documentation it says:

> The default value is UISegmentedControlNoSegment (no segment selected) until the user touches a segment. Set this property to -1 to turn off the current selection.

Maybe you want to try this last thing as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried your first 2 suggestions, to no avail. Updated code example above. I also tried your -1 to turn off the selection, but then the segmented control doesn't register the selection at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by moving my call to setSelectedSegmentIndex to inside the setNeedsLayout function, instead of calling it right after creation of the UISegmentedControl. Of course I also had to create a variable to keep track of which segment should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Resolved it by removing the previous instance of the segmentedControl from the superview before adding the new instance.

Adding the below-mentioned 3 lines of code to remove previous segmentedControl before adding the new instance of segmentedControl to the parent view.

```
self.backgroundSegmentedControl.tag = 101
if let foundView2 = segmentCell.contentView.viewWithTag(101) {
    foundView2.removeFromSuperview()
}
[segmentCell.contentView addSubview:self.backgroundSegmentedControl];
```